# Setting make options in a makefile

Tags: makefile

Can I create a makefile which will behave as if some options were passed to `make` executable?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's not possible to modify e.g. the `-j` value or add the behaviour of `-d` run-time in a Makefile. However, one nice workaround is adding a target like this:

```
debug:
        make -d debugtarget
```

Now `make debug` works just like `make -d debugtarget`. You can even make "debug" your default target and get the same effect with just `make`.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you can't. But in practice you can rerun your make session with proper options as follows:

```
ifndef __mk_ready

MAKEFLAGS += --jobs=10
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

% :
    @$(MAKE) __mk_ready=1 $@

else

# ...

endif # __mk_ready
```